# Passing Type Constructor to Var Args of `Any` Type

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> def f(x: Any*): String = "Foo"
f: (x: Any*)String
```

My understanding is that it'll take 1 or more arguments of any `Any`, and then return `"Foo"`.

```
scala> f(1, 2, List(4), "foo")
res5: String = Foo

scala> f(null)
res6: String = Foo
```

But, then I passed in a higher-kinded type:

```
scala> f(Option)
res7: String = Foo
```

... but I expected a compile-time failure since **edit - I think** it's a type constructor.

Why did `f(Option)` work, i.e. output `"Foo"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a type constructor, and there's nothing special about var args in this case. It is the companion object of `Option`. If you make `f` generic over a type parameter `A`, you can see that `Option.type` (the type of `Option`s companion object) is inferred.

```
scala> def f[A](a: A) = a
f: [A](a: A)A

scala> f(Option)
res1: Option.type = scala.Option$@59f95c5d
```